# How to import SVG or EPS files with LaTeX legends on Inkscape?

Tags: eps, matlab, svg, inkscape, matplotlib

I usually plot my functions using Matlab or Python (matplotlib) and set labels with LaTeX. Occasionally, the plots have some rendering problem and I edit their SVG or EPS files using Inkscape. The problem is that Inkscape imports the LaTeX symbols using some other fonts and I missed the original text. Is there a way to import LaTeX correctly? I'm looking something like this [post](http://bdml.stanford.edu/Main/ThesisWritingTricks).

Comment: To insert text on Inkscape exactly as in TeX you should have the fonts installed on your system. Or you can try to convert the text to curves and then Inkscape will treat them as paths.

Comment: What are the fonts that I need to use Tex on Inkscape and where can I download them? I would really prefer not to use paths instead of text, but where is the option to import text as paths or how do I do that with another program?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way that worked for me was to save the figure in `.svg` format in matplotlib. This preserves the LaTeX math symbols rendered by matplotlib when you open in Inkscape